# How to work with SIM cards (Installing applet)

Tags: gsm, javacard, sim-card, globalplatform, gemalto

I have a smart card with the following ATR:

`ATR = 3B 9E 94 80 1F 42 80 31 00 73 BE 21 10 66 54 59 53 04 4C 25 CF`.

Based on the output of [atr-parse.appspot.com](https://smartcard-atr.appspot.com/parse?) I found that it is a *MCI (Mobile Communication Company of Iran) SIM card*.

These are the info that I gained from Historical Bytes :

> (compact TLV data object)
>
> Tag: 3, Len: 1 (card service data byte)
>
> Card service data byte: 0
>
> - EF.DIR and EF.ATR access services: by GET RECORD(s) command
> - Card with MF
>
> Tag: 7, Len: 3 (card capabilities)
>
> Selection methods: 190
>
> - Record number supported
> - Short EF identifier supported
> - Implicit DF selection
> - DF selection by file identifier
> - DF selection by path
> - DF selection by full DF name
>
> Data coding byte: 33
>
> - Behaviour of write functions: proprietary
> - Value 'FF' for the first byte of BER-TLV tag fields: valid
> - Data unit in quartets: 1
>
> Command chaining, length fields and logical channels: 16
>
> - Logical channel number assignment: by the card
> - Maximum number of logical channels: 1
>
> Tag: 6, Len: 6 (pre-issuing data)
>
> Data: 54 59 53 04 4C 25 "TYS.L%"

As you see above it is mentioned that the card has a `MF`.

The problem is I can't do anything with this card. In the first step I want to list its contents. I took a look at *TS 11.11*, *TS 102.221*,*TS 131.102* and *TS 151.011* specifications.

As far as I understand from above documents the system file of the card consist of an `Master File` that its AID is `3F00` and Some DF-s and EF-s. For example base on this below table of *TS 151.011* specification I tried to select some DF-s :

[image]

These are the results :

```
Connected to RTP CCID USB Reader 0
ATR: 3B 9E 94 80 1F 42 80 31 00 73 BE 21 10 66 54 59 53 04 4C 25 CF

> APDU
> A0 A4 04 00 02 5F 30
< 6A 82

> APDU
> A4 A4 04 00 00
< 6E 00

> APDU
> A0 A4 04 00 00
< 67 00

> APDU
> 00 A4 04 00 00
< 61 13

> APDU
> 00 C0 00 00 13
< 6F 11 84 09 A0 00 00 00 62 03 01 08 01 A5 04 9F 65 01 FF
< 90 00

> APDU
> 00 A4 04 00 09 A0 00 00 00 62 03 01 08 01
< 61 13

> APDU
> A0 A4 04 00 09 A0 00 00 00 62 03 01 08 01
< 6E 00

> APDU
> 00 A4 04 00 09 A0 00 00 00 62 03 01 08 01
< 61 13

> APDU
> 00 C0 00 00 13
< 6F 11 84 09 A0 00 00 00 62 03 01 08 01 A5 04 9F 65 01 FF
< 90 00

> APDU
> 00 A4 04 00 02 3F 00
< 6A 82

> APDU
> A0 A4 04 00 02 3F 00
< 6E 00
```

As you see above I failed all of them and I could find the AID of ISD only.

I tried to list contents with *GlobalPlatformPro* tool also, but it seems that the card not support Initial Update APDU command :

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\today>java -jar gp.jar -visa2 -key 47454D5850524553534F53414D504C45 -unlock -list -v -d -i
# Detected readers from SunPCSC
[*] RTP CCID USB Reader 0
SCardConnect("RTP CCID USB Reader 0", T=*) -> T=0, 3B9E94801F4280310073BE211066545953044C25CF
SCardBeginTransaction("RTP CCID USB Reader 0")
Reader: RTP CCID USB Reader 0
ATR: 3B9E94801F4280310073BE211066545953044C25CF
More information about your card:
    http://smartcard-atr.appspot.com/parse?ATR=3B9E94801F4280310073BE211066545953044C25CF

A>> T=0 (4+0000) 00A40400 00
A<< (0019+2) (249ms) 6F118409A00000006203010801A5049F6501FF 9000
Auto-detected ISD AID: A00000006203010801
***** Card info:
A>> T=0 (4+0000) 80CA9F7F 00
A<< (0000+2) (73ms) 6A86
GET DATA(CPLC) returned SW: 6A86
NO CPLC
***** CARD DATA
A>> T=0 (4+0000) 80CA0066 00
A<< (0000+2) (81ms) 6E00
NO CARD DATA
***** KEY INFO
A>> T=0 (4+0000) 80CA00E0 00
A<< (0000+2) (82ms) 6E00
A>> T=0 (4+0000) 00CA00E0 00
A<< (0000+2) (60ms) 6E00
GET DATA(Key Information Template) not supported
A>> T=0 (4+0008) 80500000 08 FE44F8E8DF60349B 00
A<< (0000+2) (61ms) 6D00
pro.javacard.gp.GPException: INITIALIZE UPDATE failed SW: 6D00
        at pro.javacard.gp.GlobalPlatform.check(GlobalPlatform.java:1092)
        at pro.javacard.gp.GlobalPlatform.openSecureChannel(GlobalPlatform.java:398)
        at pro.javacard.gp.GPTool.main(GPTool.java:371)

C:\Users\User\Desktop\today>
```

I want to know what's wrong? How I can install java card applets on this SIM card?

Note that I already worked with Java Card successfully,but I am totally confused about these kind of SIM cards. I appreciate any one could shed any light on this issue. 
Regards.

Comment: Does your card supports SCP02??

Comment: I don't have any idea. I couldn't find the documentations. This is the same SIM that our network operator used for telecommunication.

Comment: @AnuragSharma Is there any way to check it without documents'?

Comment: Sorry that i dont know but as far as i can see your is saying 0x6D00 on initialize updated command which means it is not supported,

Comment: @AnuragSharma BTW, which kind of requirements am I need to write and upload applications on SIM cards? (Suck as Keys? APIs? ...) Is there any free tool such as GlobalPlatformPro tool? Can I use this same tool or I need another tools?

Comment: For this you need to contact your SIM vendor ask him how to install applets on this SIM card it might be using card manager PIN verification and then you will be able to send install commands.

Answer (score 3):

If you obtain the card from market (not your own development card) it's almost impossible to install applet on it since you don't know the keyset of its ISD. It is made so in order to grant only the card issuer and the card owner (MNO) full control over the content of SIM card.

Another possible explanation is that not all SIM card fully support GP nor Javacard. There are existing SIM card that only comply with 2G/3G/4G standard (GSM 11.11, 11.14, 102.222 etc) to be able for its user to authenticate to network only. Such SIMcard could own STK application as well , but it's not necessarily implemented as javacard applet.

Comment: Do you mean that it seems that my card in the question in not neither Global-Platform not Java-Card compliant?

Comment: probably yes, I was once developed such simcard. It has STK app (ported from Javacard applet) that is embedded to its OS. Such card usually exist in developing country to reduce card cost.

Comment: Isn't it possible that I have a GP and JC compliant card but I need to verify a PIN before sending other APDU commands?

Comment: Yes, It's also possible (but less likely) that you need to verify pin to gain access to initialize update command. Probably not CHV1 or CHV2 though, maybe ADMx.

Answer (score 1):

As per your last log of Initialize Update command, there can be some possibilities:
1. Scp02/Scp03 is not supported on your card, less possibility if it supports GP.
2. ISD has not configured with SCP supported parameters.
3. There is another secure channel previously ongoing at the same logical channel, on card.

As per my view there can be last 2 possibilities.

To check the 3rd one, you should try to start Scp02 with following set of steps:
1. Send cold reset (PowerON-Power-OFF)
2. Select ISD
3. Send Initialize Update command.

If it doesn't work then you need the information of ISD application parameters and from these parameters you can identify that is ISD supports SCP02/03 or not?

These parameters can be like: 'C9 04 81 02 XX YY' (here XX-supported SCP and YY-parameter 'i' value for SCP ).